# Measure the number of executed instructions including *speculative*

Tags: performance, x86, cpu-architecture, perf, speculative-execution

I'd like to measure the number of instructions executed in my program including *speculative* instructions that didn't retire.
I know that linux perf can easily report the *retired* instruction count with:

```
$ perf stat --event instructions -- <my_program>
```

Is there a way to do that? I could not find a suitable performance event under `perf list`.

Is there another proxy to measure the amount of speculative execution in the processor?

More information: I have an Intel Skylake machine, but answers relevant to other Intel/AMD processors would be great as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`instructions` counts retired instructions.  Speculative exec works in terms of uops; the CPU only cares about instruction boundaries at decode and retirement.  (And somewhat in the uop cache.)

An event like `uops_executed.thread` is probably what you want, vs. `uops_retired.retire_slots`.  But with micro-fusion, `add eax, [rdi]` is 1 fused-domain uop (issue and retire), but two unfused-domain `uops_executed.thread`.

`uops_dispatched_port.port_0` / `1` / `5` / `6` for ALU ports, and 2,3,7 load/store-address and port 4 store-data events also exist; `uops_executed.thread` should mostly(?) be the sum of those per-port counters.

To count mis-speculation, you could compare `uops_issued.any` vs. `uops_retired.retire_slots`.  That won't tell you how many of the mis-speculated uops actually got *executed* before mis-speculation was detected, and I don't know a good way to do that other than careful counting, like knowing how many unfused-domain uops there were in the `uops_retired.retire_slots` uops that retired.  That may be doable in a microbencmark loop, otherwise you'd just have to go by averages in a larger program.

(The event names I mention all exist on my Skylake-client CPU, and probably earlier and later Intel.  AMD will have very different event names.)

Comment: Thanks @Peter Cordes! Your answer helped me realize that my question is ill-defined because there are no "misspeculated instructions". Misspeculated uops terminate somewhere inside the pipeline, so the point where I measure them determines how many I'll count.